# navbar with mouse hover and mouse click both

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap responsive navbar. I want to make navbar drop down when mouse hover . When I resize my screen and small the size of browser then the same functionality of dropdown work when I click on navbar Instead of hover.

In short when full size of browser then dropdown work on mouse hover and When small size of browser it should work onclick.

Here is my Html

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div id="smNav" class="navbar-header">
<button  id="btnNav"  type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"   data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
</div>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" id="drpDown" class="dropdown-toggle"   data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
 <ul id="drpItems" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
 <li id=""><a href="#">Action</a></li>
 <li id=""><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
 <li id=""><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
 <li id="" class="divider"></li>
 <li id="" class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
 <li id=""><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
 <li id=""><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
 </ul>
```

I have attempted two ways, first one is:

```
<script>
    val = 'clck';

    });

    switch (val) {

    case'hvr':
    {

    $('#drpDown').hover(function () {


    $('#drpItems').slideDown("fast");
    });

    $('#drpItems').mouseleave(function () {

    $('#drpItems').slideUp("fast");

    });
    break;
    }
    case 'clck':
    {


    $('#drpDown').click(function () {

    $('#drpItems').slideToggle("fast");
    });

    break;
                }
```

And the other one is....

```
    $('div.collapse ').click(function () {


    });
    $('div. navbar - collapse ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function () {

    $('#drpDown').hover(function () {


    $('#drpItems').slideDown("fast")
    });

    $('#drpItems').mouseleave(function () {

    $('#drpItems').slideUp("fast");

    });

    });


    $('ul.nav li.dropdown').click(function () {


    $('#drpDown').click(function () {

    $('#drpItems').slideToggle("fast");
                             });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: There no event hover in mobile device, that's why the hover event is converted to click (touch).

Comment: Could you edit your code so it's readable?

Comment: No hover on touch devices that's why Bootstrap is click only. Screen size does not determine if it's a touch device. Tablets can be and are just as large as desktop devices.

Comment: my hover works and click also but the bug is that when I small the browser size then both click and hover working and I only want click function when browser size small

Comment: I think you should be able to change the bootstrap css in order to handle the hover for small screen size

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice little bit of code sitting on GitHub that will do what you require.

https://github.com/CWSpear/bootstrap-hover-dropdown

Enjoy.

Comment: This is only hover , i want hover when browser size is full but when I small the size of browser the same hover functionality should be convert on click dropdown